# Addon domain and second wordpress installation not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, addon-domain

I already had a Wordpress installation in `public_html/wp` directory for my primary domain name lets say `domain-one.com`. Now I added an addon domain `domain-two.com` with root directory as `public_html/govt`. Now I installed wordpress again for `domain-two.com` within directory `wp`. So now I have below directory structure -

[image]

my first website i.e. `domain-one.com` was **and** is working fine. However if I go to `domain-two.com/wp/wp-admin/` it doesn't show me login/dashboard screen instead below screen is shown.

[image]

In `public_html/` directory there are `.htaccess` and `index.php` file (for `domain-one.com`), while in `public_html/govt/` there are no such file.

Content of `public_html/.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Content of `public_html/index.php` file

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

What should I do so that `domain-two.com` shows login/dashboard screen?

**UPDATE 1**: After going through [this](http://liquidbook.com/2014/08/installing-second-wordpress-instance-subfolder/) article, I created an `.htaccess` file (and index.php) in `public_html/govt` folder and put the below content in it. I tried with content of root folder htaccess file as well. But still the problem is same in both cases.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /govt/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /govt/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Is this an apache2 server?

Comment: have you properly pointed Bluehost to your server and set up virtual hosts to direct traffic for your second site to the new directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install WordPress manually. I had the same issue. Just download WordPress, extract it and then shift the whole WordPress files in this folder. If you have already created dB, then change the config.php else it will ask you for the db creation. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for each domain hosted :wordpress auto generate `.htaccess` file and in `.htaccess` file, code is also the same as you posted here. and else addon domains are added only with `CPANEL`: addon domain software like here:

Step1

[image: step1]

Step 2

[image: step2]

Step 3

[image: step3]

Step 4

[image: step4]